# Is there a portable alternative to relational comparison of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison

I lack industry experience with the language. But in my spare time I have encountered a couple of places where I need to compare pointers, preferably with behavior defined by the standard.

First case, if I decide to use ordered binary tree as a container in my application (and not hash table) and I want equality to be the object's identity (i.e. equal means the same instance) then I find no portable way to do this.

Second, if I want to test the containment relationship between the "complete objects" and their sub-objects, I again seem to have no portable approach. That is if I have two void* pointers "p" and "q", and I have the size of the object pointed to by "q", I see no way to test whether "p" is a non-static member variable of "q" or not. I fail to find encouragement in paragraph 5.9 ("Relational operators") from the standard. The latter scenario appears, for example, in the garbage collector from this boost forum [post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/04/150748.php). I liked the general idea and started to explore it, but certain parts seem to use pointers and allocation semantics in ways which are not portable.

That is I want to know how to make the `contains` function from the following code portable:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct A {
    int x;
} a;

struct B {
    int y;
} b;

bool contains(const void *outer, size_t size, const void *inner)
{
    return (outer <= inner) &&
        (inner < static_cast<const char *>(outer) + size);
}

int main()
{
    assert(contains(&a, sizeof(a), &a.x));
    assert(contains(&b, sizeof(b), &b.y));
    assert(!contains(&a, sizeof(a), &b.y));
    assert(!contains(&b, sizeof(b), &a.x));
}
```

Thanks and best regards.

PS:
Ok, after consulting the standard again, I see that it states explicitly, as GMan informs in his answer, that the functors such as `less` and `less_equal` provide total ordering for pointers. I think it is also implied that the ordering will be consistent with the built-in comparison operators `<` and `<=`, but that point could be addressed more pedantically. The built-in operators are not predictable when the pointers do not point in the same array, or to sub-objects of the same object. I mean, what is the test for distinctiveness in this total order - the binary representation of the pointer? For example, when not comparable in well-defined manner with the built-in operators, what does it mean to be non-identical in the total order on `void*` pointers?

For member variables with the same access control, the standard defines their order in memory, i.e. when observed through pointer comparison. It is the order of appearance in the object's type definition. From the perspective of the built-in comparison operators, the first member variable has the smallest address and the last member variable has the biggest address. Also, in the section on types, it is stated that objects of a "trivially copyable type" will be laid out in memory in the range between the value of the `&` operator and the following `sizeof` characters. Now lets assume that the functors provide total order in the sense of pointers to distinct objects being distinct. Doesn't this mean that, even if inadvertently, the standard implies the behavior of the snippet above, if functors are used instead of the built-in operators in the `contains` function?

Just want to get the point clear - if the standard has omission, or simply needs clarification, or it leaves flexibility for the implementation of pointer comparison.

Comment: Your second paragraph was incoherent and rambling. I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: I made a small edit. I hope it clarifies the idea a bit.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: I added a code snippet to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for (i.e., what exactly are you trying to accomplish?), but I think this is what you want to know:

The relational functors `greater`, `greater_equal`, `less`, and `less_equal` defined in `<functional>` yield total ordering for any pointer type, even if the built-in relational operators do not.

That is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i, *j = &i;    
    int k, *l = &k;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::less<int*>()(j, l) << std::endl;
}
```

is well-defined. (Note the output is implementation-defined, but you *are* guaranteed total ordering.)

The associative containers predicate defaults to `std::less`, so it's okay to use pointers as keys.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was very useful indeed and solves the case of the first paragraph. Is there a guarantee that "less_equal<void*>()(&A,&x)" and "less<void*>()(&x,(void*)((char*)&A + sizeof(A)))" will both return true if "x" is a member variable of A.

Comment: @simeonz: I don't know what `A` or `x` is, so I can't answer. What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: I need to check if a void pointer is pointed to an object inside some block of memory that is occupied by some parent object. So, if I have an array of pointers to void P, another array of pointers to void Q, and an array S holding the respective sizes of the objects pointed by the pointers in Q, I need to find out if the objects pointed in P are members of the objects pointed to in Q.

Comment: The reason behind the problem is, that the garbage collector mentioned in my question needs to build a graph of the pointer references inside the program. However a block of memory may be referenced either as pointer to the complete object, or pointer to some member variable inside the object. This is why I need some portable test to detect if a pointer is pointed "inside" an object.

Comment: thanks, this is useful; can you give an example where these functors and built-ins are different? Also, this is probably basic, but I can't figure out what are the extra `()` are for in `std::less<int*>()(j, l)`?

Comment: @davka: If I may answer, `less` is a class template, and `less<int*>` is its instance, i.e. a de facto class. The first `()` constructs an object of type `less<int*>` and the second one calls its overloaded `operator ()`. So, what you see in `std::less<int*>()(j, l)` is a constructor followed by method call. In practice using the functor will be seldom different, but in theory (according to the standard) using the built-ins on `void*` pointers, not pointing inside the same array or object, may cause any imaginable behavior. That is, my snipped above may cause a system reset. Just in theory.

Comment: I think you can pretty much forget about "true" portability given your requirements. The C++ standard doesn't give you much more than *a* total ordering. It doesn't really make any promises about which pointers will be "less than" others, just that the ordering will be consistent and unambiguous. You'll probably have to rely on platform-specific knowledge.